# Select capture-group (mark) in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a pretty simple xml like this:

```
<myNode EMail="foo@bar.de">
<myNode EMail="alpha@beta.com">
```

I want to select only the content of `Email` with the mark-option in the search window.

[image]

As you can see, I'm able to select the whole string, but not just the content. I want to extra the raw value of the EMail-attribute. My current way of using this (+ clicking copy marked) and then run search&replace to get rid off the `"` doesn't seem to be that good.

Following similar questions on SO, I guess it should be doable with something like `/1` in the end, but that didn't do the trick. I tried using it like
`email="(.*?)"/1` but without success. Am I missing something?

In addition, I don't need `search & replace`, i simply want the content of the email node selected.

Comment: Try it like this `\bEMail="\K[^\s"]+` https://regex101.com/r/2dq2NB/1 Or if there has to be an `@` sign and a closing double quote `\bEMail="\K[^\s"@]+@[^\s"@]+(?=")` https://regex101.com/r/PUQtHU/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\bEMail="\K[^\s"@]+@[^\s"@]+(?=")
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bEMail="` Match literally preceded by a word boundary
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^\s"@]+@[^\s"@]+` Match a non whitespace string excluding double quotes containing one `@` sign
- `(?=")` Assert a double quote to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PUQtHU/1)

Or a shorter version if the format is always the same:

```
\bEMail="\K[^\s"]+(?=")
```

[image]

Comment: works like a charme. Havn't heard about `\K` until now. Always tried it with groups, but this is so much cleaner